# Expo Snack displays "not found in the registry" when adding npm package

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I am using Expo Snack but keep receiving an error when using the public npm package below. I can access the package, use it locally in my app, but through Expo Snacks, the error below happens. Any idea about it?

```
Failed to resolve dependency '@proximus/react-native-language-translation@^2.1.3' (Package '@proximus/react-native-language-translation' not found in the registry)
```

Answer (score 1):

A search for that package on npm shows it has not been updated in three years and it's build status is not going through.
[image: NPMJS screenshot]
It is a curious case as to how it works for you locally. I couldn't download the package on my end, using either npm or yarn.

Why not use a better library for what you are trying to do, like [react-native-localize](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize)